# Ember dropdown selenium xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, ember.js

How to write xpath for the ember dropdown.

```
<ul id="ember-power-select-options-ember2473" class="ember-power-select-options ember-view" aria-controls="ember-power-select-trigger-ember2473" role="listbox"> <li class="ember-power-select-option" aria-selected="false" aria-current="false" data-option-index="0" role="option">Option A
```

Since the ember id changes, how can i write xpath??

Comment: you can try with class tag

Comment: Did you try out any xpath by now? Though dynamic I still can see the regex is pretty much constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With xpath:

```
//ul[contains(@id, 'ember-power-select-options-ember')]
```

With css:

```
ul[id*='ember-power-select-options-ember']
```

Other css:

```
ul.ember-power-select-options[role=listbox]
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the value of the `id` attribute will keep changing dynamically, everytime you access the *AUT(Application Under Test)*. Hence to interact / click the dropdown you need to construct **dynamic** [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as follows:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  ul.ember-power-select-options.ember-view[id^='ember-power-select-options-ember']
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  //ul[starts-with(@id, 'ember-power-select-options-ember') and @class='ember-power-select-options ember-view']
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to click on the ember.js enabled button using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64950793/how-to-click-on-the-ember-js-enabled-button-using-selenium-and-python/64959474#64959474)
- [Selenium - Finding element based on ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276695/selenium-finding-element-based-on-ember/59282757#59282757)