# Selenium - Finding element based on ember

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am working with selenium in python 3.6 on the chrome browser.  I have programmed it to the point where I can access the website I want but I am struggling to find the text box element I am searching for.  When I inspect the element it has this code.

```
<input placeholder="" id="ember32" class="ssRegistrationField ssEmailTextboxField ember-text-field ember-view" type="email">
```

But when I try and use the given ID, it does not work and says that it cannot be found.  Here is my code (Without the text I wish to insert of the website URL):

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

browser.get('')

email = browser.find_element_by_id("ember34")
email.send_keys('')
```

I have just started using Selenium today and any help figuring out what is wrong would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(browser,5).until(
              EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'ember32')))

browser.find_element(By.ID,'ember32').send_keys('Your_Email')
```

The problem was the DOM has ember32 and your program is looking for ember34, Basic Typeo.

The code above will add an implicate wait for 5 seconds, search for ember32, and then time out if it cant find it.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ssRegistrationField.ssEmailTextboxField.ember-text-field.ember-view[id^='ember'][type='email']"))).send_keys("Max")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='ssRegistrationField ssEmailTextboxField ember-text-field ember-view' and starts-with(@id,'ember')][@type='email']"))).send_keys("Max")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to click on the ember.js enabled button using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64950793/how-to-click-on-the-ember-js-enabled-button-using-selenium-and-python/64959474#64959474)
- [Ember dropdown selenium xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653659/ember-dropdown-selenium-xpath/60548670#60548670)