# How to click on the ember.js enabled button using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, ember.js, css-selectors

I have been trying to make this clickable and I just cannot understand what I am doing wrong.
I am also trying to induce webdriverwait, so that it is clicked when it appears.

This is my code so far:

```
def order(k):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd()+"\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe") 
    driver.get("website.com/login-to-checkout")
    driver.find_element_by_id('i0116').send_keys(k["email"])
    driver.find_element_by_id('i0118').send_keys(k["password"])
    driver.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9').click()
    delay()
    #sign in button
    driver.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9').click()
    #Button below I cant get to be clicked
    with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 7)
        wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ember1053")))
        driver.find_element(By.id, "ember1053").click()
```

this is the source code for the button that I am trying to make clickable:

```
<div id="ember1037" class="btn-group m-b-lg m-t-lg order-call-to-action ember-view"><!---->        <!--biBehavior 80 means place order Place Order-->

<button aria-live="polite" type="button" tabindex="0" data-m="{&quot;aN&quot;:&quot;shoppingCart&quot;,&quot;cN&quot;:&quot;PlaceOrder&quot;,&quot;bhvr&quot;:80}" id="ember1053" class="btn theme-default btn-primary cli-purchase ember-view"><!---->            Place order

</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is an [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) element and the value of the `id` attribute of the `<button>` will keep changing dynamically, every time you access the *AUT(Application Under Test)*. Hence to `click()` on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.theme-default.btn-primary.cli-purchase.ember-view[id^='ember'][type='button'][aria-live='polite']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn theme-default btn-primary cli-purchase ember-view' and starts-with(@id,'ember')][contains(., 'Place order') and @aria-live='polite']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium - Finding element based on ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276695/selenium-finding-element-based-on-ember/59282757#59282757)
- [Ember dropdown selenium xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653659/ember-dropdown-selenium-xpath/60548670#60548670)

Comment: @Roger Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

This may help but I've had issues with webdriver not clicking on a button when I use the id to find it.
The work around I've found is using the xpath instead of the id.
Like this, it's worth a try.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="submit-button"]""").click()
```